# Upgrading your Svelte + Vite project from Vite 3.x to Vite 4.x

Tags: plugins, module, upgrade, svelte, vite

After using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) in my Svelte + Vite 3 project I noticed 2 major upgrades:

```bash
@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte  ^1.3.1  →  ^2.0.2
 vite                         ^3.2.4  →  ^4.0.4
```

I tried to upgrade the packages avoiding some possible old dependencies:

```bash
ncu -u && rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules && npm i
```

However, even with all dependencies matching the latest package versions it failed:

```bash
Failed to resolve entry for package "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you review [@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/packages/vite-plugin-svelte/CHANGELOG.md) changelog you can fix this issue just adding to your **package.json**:

```json
"type": "module"
```